# SYNTAX_ERROR: '"LastName"' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, group-by, amazon-athena, pyathena

I have a two tables, main_table & staging_table,
main_table contains original data whereas staging_table contains the few of the updated records that I have to add into with main_table data, and for that I am using unique id -**PersonID** and arrival time - **date**
Below is the query which I am able to execute into SQL

```
SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City, max(date) 
from 
(
select PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City, date from main_table
UNION
select PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City, date from staging_table
) as t
GROUP by t.PersonID;
```

but while executing into AWS Athena, I am getting following error,
**SYNTAX_ERROR: '"LastName"' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause**

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the other columns might differ and you actually want the full record from the most recent date.  If this is the case, use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from ((select PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City, date
             from main_table
            ) union all
            (select PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City, date
             from staging_table
            )
           ) p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

This select one row per `PersonId` with the most recent date.  The columns come from the most recent row.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.