# How to fix 'must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause' with 'as' clause in Presto?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, ansi-sql

This question is similar to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919887/syntax-error-lastname-must-be-an-aggregate-expression-or-appear-in-group-by), but I'm providing a simpler example. The [other query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59919952/9754418) was too advanced to make sense to me.

### Sample (fake) data

| id | gender | kg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4f5a07ca-02e0-8981-3c30-4d9924a169a3 | male | 103 |
| 4f5a07ca-02e0-8981-3c30-4d9924a169a3 | male | 85 |
| 4f5a07ca-02e0-8981-3c30-4d9924a169a3 | male | 469 |
| e05d54e9-8292-b26c-5618-8a3712b4fc44 | female | 33 |

### Desired outcome

| id | gender | kg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4f5a07ca-02e0-8981-3c30-4d9924a169a3 | male | 85 |
| e05d54e9-8292-b26c-5618-8a3712b4fc44 | female | 33 |
| e05d54e9-8292-b26c-5618-8a3712b4fc44 | female | 36 |
| 01f8bbfd-cfc6-3b97-8bc1-8da6f0b4a9a8 | female | 92 |

(Goal is having the same id only show up once, and just picking the first match, given an ordering by `kg`)

QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.gender,
    p.kg
FROM patient p
ORDER BY p.kg
GROUP BY 1
```

Error:

> 'p.gender' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

And if I change it to `GROUP BY 1, 2`, I get the same error, one column over:

> 'p.kg' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ordering by kg" combined with selecting only one value sounds awfully like `min`/`max` aggregate function. In this case `min` (for gender you can use [`min_by`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#min_by) or [`arbitrary`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#arbitrary)):

```sql
SELECT 
    p.id,
    min_by(p.gender, p.kg),
    min(p.kg)
FROM patient p
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregate function to get min/max/avg kg. Otherwise you need to replace p.kg with a subquery returning a single version, something like:

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.gender,
    (select top 1 p.kg from patient where patient.id=p.id)
FROM patient p
ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: Have you checked that this works in Presto? Cause correlated subqueries are quite limited there.

Answer (score 1):

what you need here is a window function first_value combined with distinct, rather than group-by / aggregate.

the window function + distinct pattern can sometimes be used to replicate aggregate query

```sql
select distinct 
  id
, first_value(gender) over (partition by id order by kg) gender
, first_value(kg) over (partition by id order by kg) kg
from patient
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like, however, if I partition by gender, I only get two rows in the results, one female result and one male result. Wouldn't I need to partition by id if I wanted only one weight measurement per patient? I updated the "Desired outcome" table to make this goal clearer.

Comment: @YannStoneman, yes, if you wanted 1 row for each distinct id, then you would partition by  id instead. is that what you wanted. sorry, my earlier reading of your question lead to thinking you wanted a distinct record for each gender. please see updated answer.